# Python trim whitespace in a list

Tags: python

I have this string:

```
"3a.24.5t.5a  4     1743 3150924      2786 0"
```

With this code:

```
for i in flines:
    ll = re.findall(r'\.?\w+', i)
    print ll
```

I get:

```
['3a.', '24.', '5t.', '5a', '4', '1743', '3150924', '2786', '0']
```

I need:

```
['3a.24.5t.5a', '4', '1743', '3150924', '2786', '0']
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post a more complete code example? What is flines? The code you posted doesn't make much sense. Also even if it worked, it wouldn't give the output you posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`split()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> ll = "3a.24.5t.5a  4     1743 3150924      2786 0".split()
>>> ll
['3a.24.5t.5a', '4', '1743', '3150924', '2786', '0']
```

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried without regex for ex using [split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)?

```
>>> x="3a.24.5t.5a  4     1743 3150924      2786 0"
>>> x.split()
['3a.24.5t.5a', '4', '1743', '3150924', '2786', '0']
```

or as per your code

```
for i in flines:
    ll = i.split()
    print ll
```

Answer (score 1):

In case split doesn't suit your purposes:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\S+',"3a.24.5t.5a  4     1743 3150924      2786 0")
['3a.24.5t.5a', '4', '1743', '3150924', '2786', '0']
```

Answer (score 0):

you just have to use the split function with the default arguments

suppose

```
a = "3a.24.5t.5a  4     1743 3150924      2786 0"
```

then do

```
b =a.split()
```

Comment: damn!! 3 same answers by the time i finished typing in mine :D